# Como criar uma estrutura de software sustentavel

Tags: php, arquitetura-de-software

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web, e este sistema será fornecido para diferentes clientes, acontece que esse sistema deverá ser possível fazer algumas customizações, porém deve manter um core que é igual para todos.

As áreas customizáveis seriam estilos como cor, efeitos, tamanhos, ou até páginas extras novas, e o core ira conter as funções principais do sistema.

Estas versões do sistema de cada cliente serão com base numa versão base do core, e quando este for atualizado, eu tenho que conseguir atualizar o core de todos os clientes com o minimo de impacto possível.

Existe algum framework, filosofica, conceito, ou qualquer coisa que possa me ajudar a elaborar esta estrutura de sistema?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Muitas variáveis. Muita imprevisibilidade. Não acredito em uma resposta simples e objetiva para esta questão. Depende de tanta coisa. Deve gerar um bonito debate que extende casos, mas resposta absoluta, não creio. Mas tem gente boa aí que vai trazer material...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que para o seu caso você poderia usar uma estrutura de **microservices**

Microservices ou Microserviços pode ser definido como:

> Uma abordagem para desenvolver uma
>   única aplicação como uma suíte de serviços, cada um rodando em seu
>   próprio processo e se comunicando através de mecanismos leves,
>   geralmente através de uma API HTTP. Estes serviços são construídos
>   através de pequenas responsabilidades e publicados em produção de
>   maneira independente através de processos de deploys automatizados.
>   Existe um gerenciamento centralizado mínimo destes serviços, que podem
>   serem escritos em diferentes linguagens e usarem diferentes
>   tecnologias para armazenamento de dados.

É uma forma de você dividir as funções do seu software, de uma forma que quando você precisar atualizar algum desses núcleos, o impacto nos outros seja o menor possível.

Este é um conteúdo muito completo, sugiro que você faça uma boa leitura antes de  decidir se deve usar e começar a implementar, segue alguns links para estudo:

- [Arquitetura de microserviços ou monolitica?](http://blog.caelum.com.br/arquitetura-de-microservicos-ou-monolitica/)
- [Microserviços](http://www.pedromendes.com.br/2016/01/02/microservicos)
- [Slim Framework para PHP](https://medium.com/@fidelissauro/slim-framework-criando-microservices-01-composer-e-depend%C3%AAncias-f9c8b8798205)